# Windows batch file Modulo divide

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file the run every hour on windows.
i need to have inside the batch a command that will run just every 3 hours

i tried to create an if statment

```
...some commands
if (my Condition) goto :label1
...some commands
:label1
...my label1 commands
```

My questions are:

1. what to put in (my condition) so the :label1 commands will run every 3 hours
2. on every hour when the condition is false do the script will the label1 commands? how he know to stop?

Comment: how the batch is started on every hour?How to recognize the first hour the batch is started? What means on every 3 hours - depends on the starting of the batch or on the time - e.g. - the condition should be call on 12:00;03:00;06:00..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
echo off
set hr=%TIME:~0,2%
set /A result = "%hr%%%3"
echo %result%
if %result% EQU 0 (
    echo "1"
)
echo 2
```